# Javascript - target DOM work in one case not another

Tags: javascript

I have a `javascript` that when press `Ctrl` + `Enter` it will call `CtrlEntInsertData()`:

```
function KeyPress(e) {
      var evtobj = window.event? event : e
      if (evtobj.keyCode == 13 && evtobj.ctrlKey) {
        CtrlEntInsertData();
      }
}

document.onkeydown = KeyPress;

function CtrlEntInsertData() {
var target = document.querySelector("input");
var tarpos = getPosition(target);    //!!<-- This work!
target.setAttribute('data', 10);     // Error line
console.log(tarpos.x+" "+tarpos.y);  //!!<-- This return x, y of target
   console.log(target);              //!!<-- NULL
}

function getPosition(element) {
    var xPosition = 0;
    var yPosition = 0;

    while(element) {
        xPosition += (element.offsetLeft - element.scrollLeft + element.clientLeft);
        yPosition += (element.offsetTop - element.scrollTop + element.clientTop);
        element = element.offsetParent;
    }
    return { x: xPosition, y: yPosition };
  }
```

Here is my `HTML`:

```
<div class="input" data="0" ></div>
```

I got an error:

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'target.setAttribute')

But when I use it to `getPosition()`, it did return me something. Why is this and how to get it to work?

Comment: It should be `document.querySelector(".input");` if you want to query it by class. `querySelector("input")` stands for `input` tags like `<input type="text"/>`.

Comment: To build on Yeldar's comment, if you actually do want to search on a tag name (like input) you can use getElementByTagName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This selector

```
document.querySelector("input");
```

finds a first element of tag `input`.

If you want to select an element by class `input`, you need to use

```
document.querySelector(".input");
```

Please, refer to [W3Schools reference on CSS selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code.
you should select elements accurately although I used selectByClassName I recommand you to selectById

```
function CtrlEntInsertData() {
var target = document.getElementsByClassName("input")[0];//selects first element of this class
var tarpos = getPosition(target);    
target.setAttribute('data', 10);    
console.log(tarpos.x+" "+tarpos.y);  
   console.log(target);              
}
```